# How can I convert a text file to a dictionary to be used in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing a small programming project for school, one of the main elements of my program is to be able to allow the user to enter a problem (e.g. "my phone screen is blank") and for me to iterate through each word of the string and compare it to a dictionary, and the dictionary must be an external text file, I would like help on the dictionary aspect of this. I have tried a few other methods from different posts of stack overflow but they do not seem to work.

Some lines of my dictionary include:

```
battery Have you tried charging your phone? You may need to replace your battery.
sound Your volume may be on 0 or your speakers may be broken, try using earphones.
blank Your screen may be dead, you may need a replacement.
```

Here, "battery,"sound" and "blank" are they keys with their respective values following on after, how do I plan on doing this?

Thank you!

---

[edited code]

```
def answerInput():
    print("Hello, how may I help you with your mobile device")
    a = input("Please enter your query below\n")
    return a

def solution(answer):
    string = answer
    my_dict = {}
    with open("Dictionary.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            key, value = line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit=1)
            my_dict[key] = value
            for word in string.split():
                if word == my_dict[key]:
                    print(value)
            
process = 0
answer = answerInput()
solution(answer)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: can't you store the dictionary as a JSON file? python has [JSON support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) in stdlib.

Comment: I made a few edits, now when I try compare the key to a word in my string, the program should print the corresponding value of the key, but there is no output, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
my_dict = {}  # defining it as a dictionary
with open("file.txt") as f:  # opening txt file
    for line in f:
        key, value= line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit=1)  # key is before first whitespace, value is after whitespace
        my_dict[key] = value
```

This will work well, something I have used personally.
It initiates a dictionary called `my_dict`,
opens the file and for each line it strips `\n` from the line and splits it once only. This creates two values which we call key and value which we add to the dictionary in the form `{key: value}`

Or, using dict comprehension

```py
with open("file.txt") as f:  # opening txt file
    my_dict = {k: v for k,v in (line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit=1) for line in f)}
```

Comment: Hello GAP2002, thank you for your help! It did work until I made a change in my code, I'll edit my post to show the edited code. When I try to run the code, I get no output, why is this?

Comment: @Fahzz Try for word in string.split(‘ ‘), i.e. place a space in there.